# Show that $P(X_2 \leq x \mid X_1 = x)\to0$ when $x\to-\infty$, where $(X_1,X_2)$ is normal with known conditional distribution

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution, conditional-expectation

> Assume that that the conditional distribution of $X_2$ conditionally on $X_1$ is $$f_{X_2\mid X_1}(x_2\mid x_1) = \frac{f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2)}{f_{X_1}(x_1)}  = \frac{1}{\sqrt{ 2 \pi (1- \rho^{2})}} \exp \left( -\frac{(x_{2}-\rho x_{1})^{2}}{{2(1 - \rho^{2})}} \right) $$
>   Show that $$\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow -\infty} P(X_2 \leq x \mid X_1 = x) = 0$$

**What I have done:**
$$ \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow -\infty}{ P(X_{2} \leq x \mid X_{1} = x)} = \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow -\infty}{ \int_{-\infty}^{x}} \frac{1}{ \sqrt{2 \pi (1- \rho^{2})}}  \exp \left({- \frac{(x_{2}-\rho x)^{2}}{{2(1 - \rho^{2})}}} \right) dx_{2} $$

Now I can see that  this has to be $0$ since $x\to-\infty$ and I integrate from  $-\infty$ to  $-\infty$. 
Is this correct? Any hint is welcome.

Comment: The number of typos in all this is impressive... Let me suggest that you at least correct the conditional PDF.

Comment: I am sorry. I think I fixed all typos now.

Comment: And now you have to find a convincing argument why the integral should go to $0$, the reason given in your question being rather vague.

Comment: I could argue that i can split the integral into $\int_{-\infty}^{0}$ +$\int_{0}^{x}$ where x goes to $-\infty$. Then for the second integral i switch the boundaries and I get $\int_{-\infty}^{0}  - \int_{x}^{0}$ where x goes to $-\infty$ and, thus, they cancel out.

Comment: The argument does not work since the integrand (the function in the integral) depends on $x$.

Comment: Your post was still mixing the hypotheses and the question to be solved so I tried to rearrange the whole into a more suitable format (with the idea that you could use it as a template for your next questions).

Comment: Re the mathematical question, you might note that the formula for $f_{X_2\mid X_1}$ actually means that $X_2=\rho X_1+\sqrt{1-\rho^2}Z$ where $Z$ is standard normal independent of $X_1$ hence $P(X_2\leqslant x\mid X_1=x)=P(\sqrt{1-\rho^2}Z\leqslant(1-\rho)x)$, from which the result should be clear for every $|\rho|<1$.

Comment: Another option is simply to use the change of variable $z=x_2-\rho x$ in the integral written in your post, then the integrand becomes independent of $x$ and you may apply the argument in your post (repeated in your comment). To sum up, yes, if $f$ is integrable then $$\int_{-\infty}^xf(z)dz\to0$$ when $x\to-\infty$, but no, not much can be said in general of the limit of integrals $$\int_{-\infty}^xf(x,z)dz$$

Comment: Thank you! The first solutions really helped me to understand it thanks! And now I also see my mistake concerning my original solutions! I will use this format as template for further questions!

Comment: Excellent. May I suggest that you write down an answer expanding on the two different approaches that I hinted at in my comments? The advantage for you would be to check you understood the solutions (simply reading them, you cannot be sure), the advantage for the site would be to have a complete answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to show that $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow -\infty}{ P(X_{2} \leq x | X_{1} = x)} = 0$
$$ \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow -\infty}{ P(X_{2} \leq x | X_{1} = x)} = \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow -\infty}{ \int_{-\infty}^{x}} \frac{1}{ \sqrt{2 \pi(1- \rho^{2})}}  e^{- \frac{(x_{2}-\rho x)^{2}}{{2(1 - \rho^{2})}}} dx_{2} $$
Substituting 
$$ z = x_{2}-\rho x$$
$$ dz = dx_{2} $$
and changing the bounds
$$ z = -\infty - \rho x = -\infty$$
$$ z= x - \rho x = x(1- \rho) $$
yields
$$\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow -\infty}{ \int_{-\infty}^{(1-\rho)x}} \frac{1}{ \sqrt{2 \pi(1- \rho^{2})}}  e^{- \frac{(z)^{2}}{{2(1 - \rho^{2})}}} dz =  0 $$

Comment: After the change of variable $x_2\to z$, the upper limit of the integral should be $(1-\rho)x$, not $x$.

Comment: Since $z= -\infty - \rho * x = -\infty $ and $ z =x - \rho * x = (1 - \rho)*x$.

Comment: Now the bounds are correct. Next step, you do not need to decompose the integral into two parts, it is known that for every fixed integrable function $f$, $$\int_{-\infty}^yf(z)dz\to0$$ when $y\to-\infty$.

Comment: Corrected that too and added the step with the bounds.

Answer (score 0):

I may provide some more statistical (maybe even intuitive) then mathematical answer to this question. The formula for conditional normal value distribution is $X_{1}|X_{2}=x\sim(\mu_{1}+\frac{\sigma_{1}}{\sigma_{2}}\rho(x-\mu_{2}),(1-\rho^2)\sigma_{1}^2)$. So we may see that variance is indendend of $x$ so the expectation only matters. Consequently as $x\to-\infty$ expectation, by **absolute value**, becomes very large. Then if $\frac{\sigma_{1}}{\sigma_{2}}\rho\ne0$ and $\frac{\sigma_{1}}{\sigma_{2}}\rho\ne1$ the difference between expectation and $x$ becomes higher and higher (untill very huge), so $x$ appears somewhere very far in the left side of the tail (because variance remains constant) that makes probability of getting values less then $x$ approach zero. If $\frac{\sigma_{1}}{\sigma_{2}}\rho=0$ then $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ are independend so we deal with marginal normal distribution where $P(X_{1}\leq-\infty)=0$. Finally if $\frac{\sigma_{1}}{\sigma_{2}}\rho=1$ then the difference between expectation and $x$ always will be $\mu_{1}-\mu_{2}$ so in this case it seems to me that the limit does not hold.